# Scrape Pinboard recursively with Scrapy - “Spider must return Request” error

Tags: python, recursion, scrapy, yield

In an effort to hone my python and Spark GraphX skills, I have been trying to build a graph of Pinboard users and bookmarks. In order to do so, I scrape Pinboard bookmarks recursively in the following fashion:

1. Start with a user and scrape all bookmarks
2. For each bookmark, identified by a url_slug, find all users that have also saved the same bookmark.
3. For each user from step 2, repeat the process (go to 1, ...)

Despite having tried suggestions from several threads here (including using Rules), when I try to implement this logic, I get the following error:

> ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got
>   'generator'

which I strongly suspect has to do with this mix of `yield`/`return` in my code.

Here a quick description of my code:

My main parse method finds all bookmark items for one user (also following any previous pages with bookmarks of the same user)  and yields the `parse_bookmark` method to scrape these bookmarks.

```
class PinSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pinboard'

    # Before = datetime after 1970-01-01 in seconds, used to separate the bookmark pages of a user
    def __init__(self, user='notiv', before='3000000000', *args, **kwargs):
        super(PinSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = ['https://pinboard.in/u:%s/before:%s' % (user, before)]
        self.before = before

    def parse(self, response):
        # fetches json representation of bookmarks instead of using css or xpath
        bookmarks = re.findall('bmarks\[\d+\] = (\{.*?\});', response.body.decode('utf-8'), re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

        for b in bookmarks:
            bookmark = json.loads(b)
            yield self.parse_bookmark(bookmark)

        # Get bookmarks in previous pages
        previous_page = response.css('a#top_earlier::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if previous_page:
            previous_page = response.urljoin(previous_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(previous_page, callback=self.parse)
```

This method scrapes information for a bookmark, including the corresponding url_slug, stores it in a PinscrapyItem and then yields a `scrapy.Request` to parse the url_slug:

```
def parse_bookmark(self, bookmark):
    pin = PinscrapyItem()

    pin['url_slug'] = bookmark['url_slug']
    pin['title'] = bookmark['title']
    pin['author'] = bookmark['author']

    # IF I REMOVE THE FOLLOWING LINE THE PARSING OF ONE USER WORKS (STEP 1) BUT NO STEP 2 IS PERFORMED  
    yield scrapy.Request('https://pinboard.in/url:' + pin['url_slug'], callback=self.parse_url_slug)

    return pin
```

Finally the `parse_url_slug` method finds the other users that saved this bookmark and recursively yields a `scrape.Request` to parse each one of them.

```
def parse_url_slug(self, response):
    url_slug = UrlSlugItem()

    if response.body:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'html.parser')

        users = soup.find_all("div", class_="bookmark")
        user_list = [re.findall('/u:(.*)/t:', element.a['href'], re.DOTALL) for element in users]
        user_list_flat = sum(user_list, []) # Change from list of lists to list

        url_slug['user_list'] = user_list_flat

        for user in user_list:
            yield scrapy.Request('https://pinboard.in/u:%s/before:%s' % (user, self.before), callback=self.parse)

    return url_slug
```

(In order to present the code in a more concise manner, I removed parts where I store other interesting fields or check for duplicates etc.)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your below block of code

```
yield self.parse_bookmark(bookmark)
```

Since in your `parse_bookmark` you have below two line

```
# IF I REMOVE THE FOLLOWING LINE THE PARSING OF ONE USER WORKS (STEP 1) BUT NO STEP 2 IS PERFORMED  
yield scrapy.Request('https://pinboard.in/url:' + pin['url_slug'], callback=self.parse_url_slug)

return pin
```

Since you have `yield` the return value of this function is a generator. And you are yield that generator back to Scrapy and it doesn't not know what to do with it.

Fix is simple. Change your code to below

```
yield from self.parse_bookmark(bookmark)
```

This will yield one value at a time from generator instead of generator itself. Or you can also do it like this

```
for ret in self.parse_bookmark(bookmark):
    yield ret
```

**Edit-1**

Change your functions to yield the items first

```
yield pin
yield scrapy.Request('https://pinboard.in/url:' + pin['url_slug'], callback=self.parse_url_slug)
```

And other one too

```
    url_slug['user_list'] = user_list_flat
    yield url_slug
    for user in user_list:
        yield scrapy.Request('https://pinboard.in/u:%s/before:%s' % (user, self.before), callback=self.parse)
```

Yielding later will schedule lot of other requests first it would take time when you start seeing scraped items. I ran above code with changes and it scrapes well for me

```
2017-08-20 14:02:38 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pinboard.in/u:%5B'semanticdreamer'%5D/before:3000000000>
{'url_slug': 'e1ff3a9fb18873e494ec47d806349d90fec33c66', 'title': 'Flair Conky Offers Dark & Light Version For All Linux Distributions - NoobsLab | Ubuntu/Linux News, Reviews, Tutorials, Apps', 'author': 'semanticdreamer'}
2017-08-20 14:02:38 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pinboard.in/url:d9c16292ec9019fdc8411e02fe4f3d6046185c58>
{'user_list': ['ronert', 'notiv']}
```

Comment: The codes runs, thanks! The problem is that the output file is empty. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497640/python-scrapy-output-csv-file-empty) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890731/scrapy-scrapes-data-but-no-output-to-file) indicate that I should return an Item. I thought I return one or, to be more precise, two items (a PinscrapyItem and a UrlSlugItem). Am I missing something? I'm not using a Pipeline.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the scraping itself works ('downloader/response_count': 41)

Comment: that worked, thanks so much! I would expect that even after scheduling these requests there would be a dumping at the very end. After all the response_count was larger than 0. Anyway, I appreciate your help!